Lovecraftian (but not written by Lovecraft himself) horror story featuring a body of water that glowed blue at night due to the creatures in it
I don't remember the title or author but I know that it was not written by Lovecraft himself. It was a short story I think.
It starts with a painter and his friend (the narrator) going house hunting in a remote region (I believe it was set in the US) and coming across a house which the painter liked and had a swamp or a lake near it.
In the night the body of water glows bluish in colour and it turns out that there are some odd creatures living in it that wish to either harm or assimilate the painter as they are actually humans taken over by the body of water. They are attached to a central intelligence of sorts in the lake or swamp by a tentacle like thing attached to their backs.
I think it was implied that this creature was from space but I am not sure.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you remember what the cover looked like?

Unfortunately not. It was quite some time ago, about a year ago

Was this a short story or a novel?

It was a short story I think

Not a match, but similar story: Clive Barker's Madonna. It's got a glowing swimmig pool inhabited by creatures that assimilates humans. It's about a pool complex, not a lake in a rural area.

Another close-but-not-quite-it that hits many of the same story points I'll mention for future visitors: What Moves the Dead by T. Kingfisher.

You may be in search of Ramsey Campbell's Lovecraftian story, "The inhabitant of the Lake", which appeared in the pictured collection, as well as other volumes. The story was written as a pastiche of Lovecraft's style.

In this tale, Mr. Campbell created the extraterrestrial entity Glaaki, which resembled a giant slug covered with living steel spines. Glaaki skewers people through their backs with these detachable spines to convert the victims into immortal slave-creatures, although the slaves become vulnerable to sunlight after a certain number of years due to a type of green rot specific to Glaaki's victims. Glaaki can also extend eye-tipped tentacles from its body. "The Inhabitant of the Lake" is set in the UK. The plot concerns an artist who rented a house near the lake in which Glaaki resided, and his encounters with the eldritch being and its slaves. I read this story quite a few years ago, and I don't recall if the lake glowed at night. At the end, the protagonist somehow avoids being enslaved by Glaaki, and provides the creature's detached spine for analysis.

In the story the water does not glow but there is a glowing blue stone near the lake.

Yes! Thank you so much, I've been searching for this story for so long. I remember listening to an audiobook of this as I fell asleep and ever since then I have been trying to find it but to no avail
